# Spaces in paths of LaunchAgents for launchd in (Mac) OS X

Tags: mac, launchd, characters

I try to add a LaunchAgent with a path set in WatchPaths that contains a space. I tried the plain path and I tried to escape the space character with a backspace as well as adding quotation marks around the path.

Nothing did the trick.

How can I add paths with space characters to a LaunchAgent?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake…

It actually *did* work with the backslash as escaping character.

EDIT:

So, the answer to the question “How can I add paths with space characters to a LaunchAgent?” is: “By escaping spaces with a backslash”.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I corrected my post—which actually implicitly did contain the answer—to explicitly mention the answer to the question.